# Binding LINQ query to Dropdownlist C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, binding

I am wondering how to bind this linq query that I have written to a dropdownlist in a C# web application. It is calling an XML file. I will post some of the XML, but its 2k Lines worth, so I will only post a snippet.

```html
 public void ddlBinding()
        {

            // Getting the XML file imported in
            string filePath = @"C:\Projects\MEAS\Central\MillView\PVDA\Main\PVDA\PVDA.Web\MillData.xml";
            // Set the file path
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

            // Setting a variable to dump the data into the dropdownlist
            var dropDownDataList = GetMachineInfo(xDoc, 2);


        }

        // LINQ Queries for binding
        public List<Machine> GetMachineInfo(XDocument xDoc, int machineNumber)
        {
            // Get the elements under a specific machine and create
            // a list of Machine objects
            // Different Linq queries to get the machine data entered
            // This needs to be incorporated for the mill also, this does not get the mill name
            return xDoc.XPathSelectElements("./mmsdata/mill/mach")
                               .Where(x => x.Attribute("n").Value == machineNumber.ToString())
                               .Elements()
                               .Select(x => new Machine
                               {
                                   sensName = x.Value,
                                   snsrN = Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("n").Value),
                                   calctype = x.Attribute("calctype").Value
                               }).ToList();
        }

        public class Machine
        {
            // Getting all the objects to the machine
            public int snsrN { get; set; }
            public string calctype { get; set; }
            public string sensName { get; set; }

        }
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mmsdata>
 <timestamp>Fri Jan 30 08:46:13 EST 2015</timestamp>
 <mill n="AG" name="Augusta, GA">
  <ds>
   <server>agppra</server>
   <server>agpprb</server>
  </ds>
  <mach n="1">
   <srn n="1" calctype="2CV">RL.CLP (1)</srn>
   <srn n="3" calctype="2CV">RL.CTWTIR (3)</srn>
   <srn n="4" calctype="2CV">RL.CTWTBETA (4)</srn>
   <srn n="6" calctype="2CV">RL.DNS (6)</srn>
   <srn n="7" calctype="2CV">RL.BSWT (7)</srn>
   <srn n="8" calctype="2CV">CA.BSWT (8)</srn>
   <srn n="9" calctype="2CV">SP.BSWT (9)</srn>
   <srn n="10" calctype="RAW">RL.MST (10)</srn>
   <srn n="11" calctype="RAW">CA.MST (11)</srn>
   <srn n="12" calctype="RAW">SP.MST (12)</srn>
   <srn n="13" calctype="2CV">RL.BNDRWT (13)</srn>
   <srn n="14" calctype="2CV">CA.BNDRWT (14)</srn>
   <srn n="15" calctype="2CV">SP.BNDRWT (15)</srn>
   <srn n="71" calctype="2CV">RL.ICMST (71)</srn>
   <srn n="72" calctype="2CV">CA.LATEX (72)</srn>
   <srn n="73" calctype="2CV">RL.COLOR (73)</srn>
   <srn n="74" calctype="2CV">RL.CLAY (74)</srn>
   <srn n="75" calctype="2CV">RL.LATEX (75)</srn>
   <srn n="76" calctype="2CV">CA.CLAY (76)</srn>
   <srn n="77" calctype="2CV">CA.ICMST (77)</srn>
   <srn n="78" calctype="2CV">CA.ICCTWT (78)</srn>
   <srn n="91" calctype="2CV">CTRL.HDBOXSP (91)</srn>
   <srn n="92" calctype="2CV">CTRL.CTWTSP (92)</srn>
   <srn n="93" calctype="2CV">CTRL.HDBOXFB (93)</srn>
   <srn n="94" calctype="2CV">CTRL.CTWTFB (94)</srn>
  </mach>
  <mach n="2">
   <srn n="1" calctype="2CV">RL.CLP (1)</srn>
   <srn n="4" calctype="2CV">RL.CTWTBETA (4)</srn>
   <srn n="7" calctype="2CV">RL.BSWT (7)</srn>
   <srn n="8" calctype="2CV">CA.BSWT (8)</srn>
   <srn n="9" calctype="2CV">SP.BSWT (9)</srn>
   <srn n="10" calctype="RAW">RL.MST (10)</srn>
   <srn n="11" calctype="RAW">CA.MST (11)</srn>
   <srn n="12" calctype="RAW">SP.MST (12)</srn>
   <srn n="13" calctype="2CV">RL.CNDWT (13)</srn>
   <srn n="14" calctype="2CV">CA.CNDWT (14)</srn>
   <srn n="15" calctype="2CV">SP.CNDWT (15)</srn>
   <srn n="81" calctype="RAW">IC.MSTCS (81)</srn>
   <srn n="82" calctype="2CV">IC.CTWT1 (82)</srn>
   <srn n="84" calctype="RAW">RL.MSTCS (84)</srn>
   <srn n="85" calctype="2CV">RL.CTWT2 (85)</srn>
   <srn n="86" calctype="2CV">RL.CTWTIR (86)</srn>
   <srn n="91" calctype="RAW">CTRL.HDBOXSP (91)</srn>
   <srn n="93" calctype="2CV">CTRL.THRMOSP (93)</srn>
   <srn n="94" calctype="2CV">CTRL.CTWTSP (94)</srn>
  </mach>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding LINQ Queries and XML to DropDownLists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484547/binding-linq-queries-and-xml-to-dropdownlists)

Comment: This is the same question as [the one you asked 4 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484547/binding-linq-queries-and-xml-to-dropdownlists) (and the one you asked this morning that you've since deleted).  Why not make that one better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a collection of elements that you are planning on binding to the DropDownList, you'll simply need to determine which properties are going to be used for the `Text` and the `Value` :

```
// Bind your Machines to your DropDownList
MachinesDropDown.DataSource = GetMachineInfo(xDoc, 2);
// Set your text / value properties
MachinesDropDown.DataTextField = "snsrN";
MachinesDropDown.DataValueField = "orignalPathId";
// Actually bind the contents to be reflected in the UI
MachinesDropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: This will only add the information for the <mach n="2">. I don't just need the ones that have "2" I have multiple different ones going all the way up to 40. is there a different way to add these numbers since I wont be able to add commas to separate them?

Answer (score 0):

```
yourddl.DataSource=dropDownDataList;
yourddl.DataValueField=<value-property name>;

yourddl.DataTextField=<text-property name>;
yourddl.DataBind();
```